# LiteDB insert or retrieve master's details List

Tags: c#, sqlite, litedb

How can we insert or retrieve  master's details from the below represented `Detail` property using LiteDB (LiteDatabase) C#.net library?

```
class myEntityMaster{
        public int ID {get;set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public List<myEntityDetail> Detail {get;set;} // this is the variable I want to valorize

}
class myEntityDetail{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int MasterID {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Please note that I tried performing `LiteDatabase.Insert()` of `myEntityMaster` having `Detail` property filled with items, however when I call any `LiteDatabase.Find` function, the `Detail` property will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BsonRef](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/wiki/DbRef) for doing this.

Or BsonMapper

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

BsonMapper.Global.Entity<Order>()
    .DbRef(x => x.Products, "products");
```

Usage

```
db.Query<Order>()
    .Include(x => x.Customer)
    .Include(x => x.Products)
    .ToList();
```